# 'I like how my family is supporting me with this?' 'I like how my family is supporting me in this?'

Tags: single-word-requests, grammar, word-usage, prepositions

Which one is correct?

'I like how my family is supporting me with this?'

'I like how my family is supporting me in this?'

So this is in context of they(the family) is supporting me with the decision I took for myself.

Answer (score -1):

You need to look into the preposition you are using:
'I like how my family is supporting me **with** this?' means i like how my family is supporting me with this (refer possession the family is using to support you)

'I like how my family is supporting me **in** this?' means i like how my family is supporting me in this (refer something the family is supporting you to achieve)